# Turn string into array

Tags: php

This should be a simple task, but I guess my head is a bit overheated currently.

How do I **correctly** turn a GET string with the value "status[30]" into an array, like:

```
array ( status => 30 );
```

I could use something like this:

```
$arr = array ( 'status' => str_replace( array( 'status[', ']' ), null, $_GET['status'] ) );
```

but there has to be a better way.

Comment: Can you show an example GET string you are working with?

Comment: Cant you simply do $arr[] = $_GET["Status"]  ?

Comment: Actually, perhaps more importantly is how are you getting that `$_GET` variable in the first place? Is it an HTML form?

Comment: Yes, it comes from a GET form the `$_GET['status']` value contains `status[x]`;

Comment: @JoshKirkpatrick That will give me `Array
(
    [0] => status[30]
)
`

Comment: Can't you just send a JSON `{"status": 30}` instead of `status[30]` so that you can apply `json_decode` on `$_GET['status']` ?

Comment: I can't change the GET value, it comes from a webservice form that I have no access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr = [];
$getValue = "status[30]";

if (preg_match('#(\w+)\[(\w+)\]#', $getValue, $matches))
    $arr[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];

print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [status] => 30
)
```

Comment: With no error checking, your code might as well be `$arr = ["status"=>30];`. Just saying...